# Implementing GATT Server with Delphi and Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, server, gatt

I want to implement a GATT Server in Delphi and Windows 10.
I tried this example with Delphi 10.2.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ggs: TBluetoothGattServer;
  service: TBluetoothGattService;
  pp: TBluetoothPropertyFlags;
  chara: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic;
begin
  btLE.Enabled := True;
  ggs := btLE.GetGattServer;
  if ggs <> nil then
  Begin
    service := ggs.CreateService
      (StringToGUID('{27EFDF1D-2D6F-4AB2-9783-E288DB80D5F1}'),
      TBluetoothServiceType.Primary);

    chara := ggs.CreateCharacteristic(service,
      StringToGUID('{90C16494-5AD1-48AD-B567-952359AAB3F1}'),
      [TBluetoothProperty.Notify, TBluetoothProperty.Indicate,
      TBluetoothProperty.Read, TBluetoothProperty.Write], 'RemodeLEServer');
    ggs.AddService(service);
    btLE.Enabled := True;
  end
  else
    showmessage('impossibile creare il service ');
end;
```

But it gives this exception in "CreateService" function:

> Not supported on this platform

Microsoft says since "Windows 10 Creators Update" it supports GATT Server.
But according to Embarcadero, they say:

> Note: WinRT Bluetooth API provides support for BLE advertising data
> through the manufacturer-specific data field, but it does not fully
> implement GATT Server functionalities.

So the TBluetoothLE seems not to support GATT Server on Windows 10. Is there any other way to implement GATT Server on Windows 10?
I want to simulate a Bluetooth Keyboard on Windows for Android.

Comment: The [8 year old blog article where you copied the code from](https://synaptica.info/en/2016/09/07/testing-bluetoothle-delphi-dx-10/) also states "_On my Windows system the LE does not function at on my pc (Intel i7/ Windows 10 / SiteCom Bluetooth). But with classic Bluetooth all function well_" and that the code was for "_a server app for my MacBook_". Try creating a UWP app instead of a Win32 program - that could be the platform being supported on Win10.

Comment: As a side note: I needed to update embas implementation of the BTLE communication a few times - they are often way behind the api changes that Microsoft did - actually some of Microsofts changed rendered the BTLE components unusable. My suggestion is to drop their implementation and try to start all over from the Microsoft examples. (like https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement)